# Cascading parameter in SSRS(Visual Studios 2012) not working with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

So I am working on a report that contains multiple parameters. For the most part I have everything working except for this one parameter, which I'll call **parameter A**. Basically, **parameter A** is a list of usernames that gets filtered based two other parameters: **period parameter** (ie 2013 or 2014) and by **country parameter** (2 = USA, 3 = UK, etc etc).

**Parameter A** is a cascading parameter with a dataset that is dependent on the previous paramenters. Users are able to select the period in the **period parameter**(multi value select is not allowed in this parameter), and the country in the **country parameter**(multi value select is allowed).

In the dataset for **Parameter A**, I have this where clause:

```
where u.username is not null  
and c.period = @period  
and c.Country_ID = @Country_ID
```

So when the user selects one country, the report works fine...but if they select multiple countries, the report breaks. Is there something I can do with the SQL code or in SSRS to let users select multiple countries and not break the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to implement a split function that can use a comma-delimited parameter.  So your where clause would be more like:

```
where u.username is not null
and c.period=@period
and c.CountryID in (SELECT item from [fn_split](@Country_ID))
```

See this article for more information: [Split Function](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666620/T-SQL-Most-Practical-Split-Function)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Going off what you wrote, I tried "and (c.Country_ID in (@Country))" and for some reason that worked. Thanks for the help!